# get Office value off mysites in sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to get the value “Office” off the Mysite of a user in a Sharepoint 2010 site using the following code:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;

      SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(oSite);

        UserProfileManager manager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

          UserProfile profile = manager.GetUserProfile(oUser.ToString());
                                        var Office = profile[PropertyConstants.Office].Value;
                                        var faxnum= profile[PropertyConstants.fax].Value;
```

Whereas the number and many other values works fine, the Office always returns Null. I believe it is because is managed metadata but I am not sure that is the problem.

I have also tried different variations of the same code but no joy.

any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Office = profile[PropertyConstants.Office] != null ? profile[PropertyConstants.Office].Value : String.Empty;
```

Try handle the null first.

Comment: Yeap I discovered that the property Office cannot be changed by the User but It might be updated, maybe from AD?